# Оптимальная запись LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой, мой код выглядит как-то громоздко. Из-за условия, по которому я хочу выбрать записи из определенной таблицы. 
У меня есть таблица, я делаю выборку по 2м строковым полям (EventName, VenueName).
Также есть какие-то входные данные (названия, по которым я ищу, допустим на входе EN = 'MyEvent' и VN = 'MyVenue') Мне нужно выбрать записи где

`EventName == EN & VenueName == VN` + нужно добавить к выборке записи, где

`EventName == EN & VenueName == null` или

`EventName == null & VenueName == VN.` Т.е. просто написать

`EventName == EN | VenueName == VN` не получится. 
Можно ли как-нибудь оптимальнее записать это выражение проще моего?

```
dynamicNotes =
                dynamicNotes.Where(
                    x => ((x.VenueName.Equals(searchModel.VenueName)) && (x.EventName.Equals(searchModel.EventName))) 
                    || (x.VenueName.Equals(searchModel.VenueName)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EventName))
                    || (x.EventName.Equals(searchModel.EventName)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.VenueName)));
```

Comment: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html

Comment: А это у вас не outer join случайно?

Comment: @VladD полагаю нет, мне нужно достать все записи, кроме тех, где в одной EventName и VenueName не подходят под первое условие

Comment: т.е. если на ходе EN = 'e' и VN = 'n' под мое уловие попадус даписи 
1) EN = 'e', VN = 'n' 2) EN = 'e', VN = null 3) EN= null, VN = 'n' 
но не подойдет запись EN='e', VN='something' или EN='something', VN = 'n'

Comment: Судя по коду, вы вызываете метод `Equals` на свойствах, которые могут быть равны `null`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это отложеный запрос, который будет конвертирован в SQL так что все нормально)

Comment: Тогда стоит написать в вопросе, что это именно Linq to Sql, а не Linq to Objects.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, буду иметь в виду

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете составить список предикатов заранее, в целом это не уменьшит колличество кода, однако может облегчить понимание, за счет того что каждый фильт будет иметь осмысленное имя.

```
Func<dynamicNote, bool> fullMath      = (x) => x.VenueName.Equals(searchModel.VenueName) && x.EventName.Equals(searchModel.EventName);
Func<dynamicNote, bool> onlyVenueName = (x) => x.VenueName.Equals(searchModel.VenueName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EventName);
Func<dynamicNote, bool> onlyEventName = (x) => x.EventName.Equals(searchModel.EventName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.VenueName);
Func<dynamicNote, bool> allRules = (x) => fullMath(x) || onlyVenueName(x) || onlyEventName(x);


dynamicNotes = dynamicNotes.Where(allRules);
```